# Upgrading from Server 2008r2 to 2012r2 with IIS service

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade Windows Server 2008r2 to 2012r2. Currently I am running IIS and I have a few questions about the upgrade process.

1. Can I do an in-place upgrade directly from server 2008r2 to 2012r2?
2. If I successfully perform an in-place upgrade, will my setting for IIS be preserved?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Build a new server, and then use Web Deploy to sync the two, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/synchronize-iis

Answer (score 1):

[Here is](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/installation-and-upgrade) the document from Microsoft that explains the Windows Server upgrade paths.  Generally, it is not recommended to perform an in-place upgrade of Windows server unless you are running a virtual machine. In any event, if you do plan on upgrading Windows server, make sure you make a copy of the server (assuming you are running a VM) and do a test upgrade before you upgrade the production server. There is no way to know for sure what problems will arise without building a test server.